# jquery functions stopped working on github pages

Tags: jquery, github, github-pages

When I added my codes to gh-pages and pushed it to GitHub, the jquery functions stopped working in the shared link. Does anyone know why?

https://ali-shariatii.github.io/jquery-exam/

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues going on, based on Dev Toolbar.

1. You're trying to serve insecure content over https. I'd fix all HTTP:// calls to https://.
2. You have failed resources (error 404) in your project. I'd check the pathnames and see if there might be an issue.
3. You don't seem to be including jQuery anywhere. You can use the jQuery CDN in your HTML to handle that. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

[image]